# How to find missing words from a designated array/list?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a list of words I need to verify are included in hundreds of documents.

I figured out how to highlight/color words from the list which are found within the document (code below).

I need to know which words are missing.

```vb
Sub HighlightWords()
    Dim vWords As Variant
    Dim sWord As Variant

    vWords = Array("SQL query", "Selenium", "Cucumber", "Rest-Assured", "Rest assured", "REST API", "TestNG", "SVN", "Subversion", "Maven", "IntelliJ", "Ecliipse", "Confluence", "JIRA", "Sauce Labs", "GitLab", "HTML", "XPATH", "CSS", "Object Oriented Programming", "Object-Orienting Programming", "OOP")

    For Each sWord In vWords
        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
        Selection.Find.Replacement.Highlight = wdYellow
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = sWord
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = True
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = True
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Next sWord
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code will display the missing terms in a message box.

```
Sub HighlightWords()
    Dim vWords As Variant
    Dim sWord As Variant
    Dim Missing As String

    vWords = Array("SQL query", "Selenium", "Cucumber", "Rest-Assured", "Rest assured", "REST API", "TestNG", "SVN", "Subversion", "Maven", "IntelliJ", "Ecliipse", "Confluence", "JIRA", "Sauce Labs", "GitLab", "HTML", "XPATH", "CSS", "Object Oriented Programming", "Object-Orienting Programming", "OOP")

    For Each sWord In vWords
        With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.Highlight = wdYellow
            .Text = sWord
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = True
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = True
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            If Not .Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceAll) Then Missing = Missing & sWord & ", "
        End With
    Next sWord
    If Not Missing = vbNullString Then _
        MsgBox "Missing terms:" & vbCr & vbCr & Left(Missing, Len(Missing) - 2)
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting an error message for, "MsgBox "Missing terms:" & vbCr & vbCr & Left(Missing, Len(Missing) - 2)", that says, "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument"... and also, where does the message box appear?

Comment: @JenTubbesing - sorry just threw that together without thinking about it. The error is because there are no missing words. Have edited code to avoid that. Message box will only display if there are missing terms and should display in center of screen.

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you a list of the missing words as collection or array:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FindMissingWords()
    Dim vWords() As Variant
    vWords = Array("SQL query", "Selenium", "Cucumber", "Rest-Assured", "Rest assured", "REST API", "TestNG", "SVN", "Subversion", "Maven", "IntelliJ", "Ecliipse", "Confluence", "JIRA", "Sauce Labs", "GitLab", "HTML", "XPATH", "CSS", "Object Oriented Programming", "Object-Orienting Programming", "OOP")
    
    Dim MissingWords As New Collection
    
    Dim sWord As Variant
    For Each sWord In vWords
        If Not IsKeywordInRange(sWord, ThisDocument.Range) Then
            MissingWords.Add sWord
        End If
    Next sWord
    
    If MissingWords.Count > 0 Then
        MsgBox "The following " & MissingWords.Count & " words are missing: " & Join(CollectionToArray(MissingWords), ", "), vbExclamation
    Else
        MsgBox "No words are missing.", vbInformation
    End If
End Sub

Public Function IsKeywordInRange(ByVal Keyword As String, ByVal InRange As Range) As Boolean
    'check if a keyword is in the range
    
    With InRange.Find
        .Text = Keyword
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    
    IsKeywordInRange = InRange.Find.Execute
End Function

Public Function CollectionToArray(ByVal Coll As Collection, Optional ByVal StartIdx As Long, Optional ByVal Size As Long) As Variant
    ' Convert a collection into an array
    
    Dim Arr() As Variant
    Dim Ci As Variant   ' Collection element
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Make sure Size is not less than collection size
    If Size < Coll.Count Then Size = Coll.Count
    
    ' Transfer collection to array
    ReDim Arr(StartIdx To StartIdx + Size - 1)
    For Each Ci In Coll
        Arr(i) = Ci
        i = i + 1
    Next

    CollectionToArray = Arr
End Function
```

Note that outsourcing the test if a keyword is in the document into a function makes your code more readable and it is easier to test or re-use.

Comment: Ok, I'm waaaay out of my league here. I've added this exact code, and I get the pop up message that says ALL of the words are missing, although I can see some of them there. I can't even get my original, "highlight the words I've listed" macro to work that I created last night... it just went away.

Comment: @JenTubbesing `If Not IsKeywordInRange(sWord, ThisDocument.Range) Then` searches the word in `ThisDocument.Range` so you may want to change it to `Selection.Range` to only search in the selection. `ThisDocument` refers to the document the code is written in. Maybe you want to use `ActiveDocument.Range` which refers to the document that is on top (has focus). This depends on where you have put your code, so you might need to change it to what you need.